¿Cuál es la mejor práctica para declarar funciones en JavaScript, usando let o const?
Estoy escribiendo código en JavaScript y me preguntaba cuál es la mejor práctica para declarar funciones: ¿debería usar let o const? ¿Hay algún beneficio claro de usar uno sobre el otro en términos de rendimiento, legibilidad o mantenibilidad del código? Agradecería cualquier orientación sobre cuál es la mejor opción en diferentes situaciones.

No se por qué se está votando para cerrar esta pregunta por ser basada en opiniones. Se puede responder de forma objetiva a la pregunta de si hay ventajas en términos de rendimiento, legibilidad y mantenibilidad del código. Por favor, no demos al botón de cerrar cada vez que veamos una pregunta teórica o relacionada con las buenas prácticas sin pararnos a pensar un poco; hay preguntas como ésta, que se pueden responder total o parcialmente de forma objetiva sin recurrir a opiniones personales.

La diferencia entre poner let o const al "declarar una función" (técnicamente las funciones se declaran con function, pero obviando eso...) es exactamente la misma diferencia entre cualquier otra variable let o const y tienes una respuesta genial aquí. Igualmente, la pregunta debería ser cerrada si no basado en opiniones basado en la duplicada.

Bienvenida Isabel.
Es simple, let es una vatiable, y una función no debería es posible modificar en un futuro. Por lo que debería usarse "const" ya que las constantes no se pueden modificar.

¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? var, let, const... o nada en Javascript

@padaleiana Claramente no, porque las respuestas de la otra pregunta se refieren al scope y no ahondan en diferencias de rendimiento y mejores prácticas

No veo lo "basado de opiniones" usar const puede tener mejor performance que "let", puede tener peor o puede ser igual, el caso es que tiene una respuesta objetiva, yo no tengo idea cual es, pero sí sé que usar const (cuando corresponda) tiene beneficios de seguridad objetivos y su uso es promovido como una buena práctica, tanto que muchos linter avisan que deben utilizarse. Se abusa en cerrar preguntas referidas a buenas prácticas, como si el desarrollo de software no fuera una disciplina orientada a la técnica

const si no planeas reasignar la función después de declararla. Esto es útil cuando tienes una función que no cambiará a lo largo de tu código. Usar const proporciona claridad al lector de tu código, ya que indica que la función no será reasignada.
const functionName = () => {
  // Código de la función
};

let si planeas reasignar la función más adelante en tu código. Esto puede ser útil en situaciones donde necesitas cambiar la implementación de la función según ciertas condiciones o eventos.
let functionName = () => {
  // Implementación inicial de la función
};

// Más adelante en el código, puedes reasignar la función
functionName = () => {
  // Nueva implementación de la función
};

